# I can not connect actionbarsherlock to the project

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I downloaded .zip file actionbarsherlock of http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html. unpacked. created a new project in eclipse from the source actionbarsherlock folder library. compiled for android 3.2-Google API. in the project properties android said checkbox is library. compile your project by android 3.2-Google API. open the project properties android, trying to add a library actionbarsherlock, apply, ok. but nothing happens. open the properties of their project and the library actionbarsherlock marked a red cross. using JRE 1.6. Can someone tell what I'm doing wrong or a good link to instructions?
Sorry google translate

Answer (score 7):

The library project must be on the same partition as your project. When you have them on the same partition, Eclipse adds the library using a relative path and it works.

Comment: true accept this . Actually any library project that has to referenced from eclipse requires the same path.

Comment: @Mick "on the same partition" means on the same disk partition/drive. You'll have problems if lets say you have the project in C:\workspace and lib in D:\downloads\ActionBarSherlock
Just move them together on C: or D:

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like the path to the ABS library could be wrong.  Steps are as follows.

1.) Start new Android project - From existing source

- Use the JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-436230d/library as your source.

2.) Right click on the abs project - Select properties - Select Android

- Make sure that, towards the bottom, the "is library" check box is checked.

3.) Right click on **YOUR** project - Select properties - Select Android

- Click add
- The ABS library should be listed in the box there.  Select it and you now how it imported in your project.

Don't forget to include in your AndroidManifest.xml to set the style for each activity that will have the ActionBar you must add the following line:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
```

One other thing.  As far as I know, the ActionBarSherlock project must remain in your package explorer.  Make sure that you aren't deleting it.  That could be causing the path error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what you wrote me it is. abs visible when you select the library but it is not included in my project for some reason. Now try to connect greendroid. Here I have it connected just fine displays in my project Package Explorer as the Library Projects> greendroid.jar. that is, a library is connected but does not want abs.

Comment: Now import the abs did not create a new project from an existing source. such as appeared in the project. although this also failed. could this be due to bugs eclipse?

Comment: @dozhdik, Please copy and paste the errors that you have from either your logcat or your console.  I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.

Comment: restarted eclipse - once all the libraries are gone. horror.

Answer (score 0):

Put the library in your C:\ drive or the Operating System drive. Do not copy the workspace - I believe it would resolve the issue you're seeing. It really helped me after several hours of strife.