# How to add library of ActionBarSherlock to project?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How to add library of ActionBarSherlock to project? I tried to add library in Android->Library but can't add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had same situation as Dhiren (red cross). Have moved source folder of Sherlock library to my Eclipse workspace folder, imported it again and problem was resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Both answers above are close to the solution but not close enough. Here's is how i solved this issue.

**1.** Install android sdk version 14

**2.** Import the ActionBarSherlock project you downloaded to Eclipse

**3. VERY IMPORTANT** do this before step 4 In your project look for android-support-v4.jar If you find it then delete it.

**4.** Right click on the project you want to use the custom action bar /Properties/Library/Add and add the library project.

If you get an error after step 4 like `Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies` then repeat step 3.

Hope this helps others and have a nice day.

Comment: but not work, after click on ok, it will show red cross icon instead of green tick icon.

Comment: Both `actionBarSherlock` and your project should be in the same Path!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

Properties -> Android -> add -> ABS

[image]

Comment: but not work, after click on ok, it will show red cross icon instead of green tick icon.

Answer (score 1):

1) Import the Sherlock Library as a project in eclipse IDE.

2) In your target project, Make `Right Click on Project Node`, 
      Select`Properties-->Android`
      Scroll Down to Library Section Then `Select-->Add Button --> A wizard opens select the Sherlock library project and press Ok button Again press Ok button in properties window`.

Comment: but not work, after click on ok, it will show red cross icon instead of green tick icon.

Answer (score 0):

Go the the Sherlock library project in eclipse, and open the project.properties file...Check if android.library=true...if it is false, check it to true :)

Comment: but not work, after click on ok, it will show red cross icon instead of green tick icon.

Answer (score 0):

I've solced same issue(red cross icon instead of green tick) folowed [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602364/i-can-not-connect-actionbarsherlock-to-the-project) in this thread:
"... The library project must be on the same partition as your project."

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By following all these steps it works for me.

1. File->import->Existing Project into Workspace -> Click Next
2. In Select Root Directory,Browse and find the Library Folder in **AndroidBarSherlock** Folder.Select the Library .Then Click OK.
3. Select copy projects into Workspace.Then click Finish.
4. Then Your Action Sherlock Library is imported.
5. Right Click Your Project you need to add, Properties -> Android -> Add -> Library -> press OK

Answer (score 0):

Befor adding **ActionBarSherlock** *library* to your project you must Right Click **ABS** *library* chose **Android Tools** -> **Add Support Library** (do the same thing to your project)