# use actionbar in android 2.3 programming

Tags: android, android-actionbar, tabview

I have been using `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)`; in my app but the target device is android 2.3.2 and does not support this code.
Is there any solution to have actionbar and tabview in android 2.3?

Answer (score 2):

The solution for getting using the `ActionBar` in versions prior to 3.0 is called `ActionBarSherlock`, and enables you to give the user a unified experience across the Android versions.

Link to the website: [ActionBarSherlock.com](http://actionbarsherlock.com)

There's actually also something called `ActionBarCompat` ([read more here](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/samples/ActionBarCompat)), but it's really inferior to `ActionBarSherlock`.

Edit: You'll find a lot of useful samples within the project hierarchy, but this should probably be the thing you're looking to accomplish: [TabNavigation.java](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java)

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionbarSherlock: [http://actionbarsherlock.com/‎](http://actionbarsherlock.com/%E2%80%8E)
Here is the tutorial for using tabs with ActionbarSherlock : http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-fragment-tabs-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah ActionbarSherlock is a best way to do it.

Here is how to add it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003361/how-to-add-library-of-actionbarsherlock-to-project)